# Is there anything like Heroku for deploying Clojure style webapps?

Tags: clojure

I am looking at deploying a Clojure web app, and I remember using Heroku for rails which was brilliant. Is there anything similar available for Clojure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of July 2011, Heroku now officially supports Clojure:

> We're very excited to announce
>   official support for Clojure, going
>   into public beta as of today.

http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/7/5/clojure_on_heroku/

Answer (score 6):

Currently, the closest there is to Heroku for Clojure is... Heroku: https://gist.github.com/1001206

Courtesy of the new [Celadon Cedar](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/5/31/celadon_cedar/) stack.

Answer (score 3):

Google App Engine! GAE supports Java and hence Clojure. I don't have any personal experience of such a project, but [this blog](http://compojureongae.posterous.com/) seems to have relevent tutorials. Google for it and you'll find some more links like [this](http://www.fatvat.co.uk/2009/05/clojure-on-google-app-engine.html).

Comment: Also https://github.com/gcv/appengine-magic makes development in clojure for gae alot easier. excelent library!

Comment: @Mikael Sundberg You should add that as an answer, because I was going to but you were here first ;)

Answer (score 2):

You might also look at stax.net which offers a full Java container deployment (without the restrictions imposed by Google App Engine). CloudBees just bought Stax so Stax will become CloudBees RUN@Cloud service (according to their recent webinar).

You can read how to deploy Clojure on CloudBees here: https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/entries/452746-clojure-deployment-on-cloudbees